# Turbolinks interfering despite data-no-turbolink in body tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a view that is changing look depending on parameters received, but [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) prevented a jQuery `toggle` function to work properly so I added `data-no-turbolink` to the body tag for that view, and it solved it.

But if navigating to another controller/action and then back, then that page still doesn't allow the jQuery function to work properly - despite of the `data-no-turbolink` in body tag. Then only way to resolve this is inserting `data-no-turbolink` to all pages, i.e. disabling turbolinks all together.

**I want the jQuery toogle function to work on my page, how do I accomplish this without turbolinks interfering?**

Comment: You don't ask a question, so I'm not sure what you want to achieve. It's possible to have jQuery and Turbolinks. Other have asked this question.

Comment: There's an issue. I want to solve the issue. Please point me to those questions where a solution is provided.

Comment: Maybe this helps you to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links

Comment: Thanks, but the suggested answers didn't solve it :/